# Is it possible to have client-to-client communication in gRPC?

Tags: grpc

I understand that gRPC is designed for client-server architecture. A server provides remote services and clients obtain the services by calling the defined RPCs. But is it possible for a client also defines a service so that other clients can request services from that client too?

An example, a server knows every client's locations and can inform other clients about the location information. A client, upon receiving the other clients' locations from the server, can now directly call the services provided by other clients.

Can gRPC do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

The terms "client" and "server" are overloaded in this context and would be better thought of as (stub) caller  and (implementation) receiver. It's possible for the client and server to be the same process but then you don't need the complexity of gRPC.

There's no prohibition on some entity functioning as both a caller ("client") and receiver ("server"). This situation arises commonly, in peer-peer networks and in micro-services where some original client calls some service which (acts as a client and) then calls various other services ....